# How can I see which of my answers have been awarded bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty, data-explorer

Is there an SEDE query or other way to see which of my (or any other user's) answers have been awarded a bounty?

Comment: Your answers that earned a bounty are on your profile - http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=bounties

Comment: @bluefeet well now I feel dumb.  Didn't realize there was an "offered" and "earned" section, I always thought it was just "active."  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask for SEDE, you get [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472244) shows your answers that received a bounty, the amount and the user who started the bounty.

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
     , v.bountyamount
     , vs.userid as [User Link]
from posts p 
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
inner join votes vs on vs.postid = p.parentid
where v.votetypeid = 9 -- bounty
and vs.votetypeid = 8
and p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?2415822## 
order by v.bountyamount desc
```

I joined on the votes table for both bounty start and bounty end so you get the user who started the bounty and the bounty amount.

At the time of posting SEDE reveals the following bounties for you:

[image]

<sub>some users might notice that they have multiple rows for the same answer. That is because you're awesome</sub>

Comment: Thanks rene, nice query.