# Find the questions I've offered a bounty for

Tags: support, bounty, search

I want to see all of the questions I've offered a bounty for. I don't mean those that currently have a bounty on them only.

How do I find those?

Comment: and in case you're interested in the bounties earned: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321142/how-can-i-see-which-of-my-answers-have-been-awarded-bounties

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a tab for this in your profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/939213/ispiro?tab=bounties&sort=offered

You can choose between currently active, all offered bounties, and bounties you've earned.

Comment: Thanks. What happened to my eye-brain coordination?? I checked there... Anyway, should I delete my question? I see I can't because of your answer. If you think the question should be deleted, please remove your answer and notify me. Thanks again.

Comment: This question could be helpful to future users. I don't see any reason to delete it. Now that you have the answer, it could be seem obvious, but it is not so evident. I know there is a way to look at the questions for which I gave a bounty, but I have to find it all the times; so, I can assure you it's not that immediate to see.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks. And by the way, I'm not notified when you comment back to me unless you add the `@ispiro` since this is not my post.

Comment: @ispiro No, you are notified because you are the only one, apart me, commenting on this post.

Comment: Never mind, I think I remembered wrong: _Note if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is not included._ (I apologize for the notifications animuson is getting.)